# Compound Query from loop - Parse Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, parse-platform, global-variables

In the app Im working on, users select a set of "tags" among a list, then I need to query all items which include at least one of those tags.
To do so, I want to use compound queries.

**documentation from Parse.com**

```
var lotsOfWins = PFQuery(className:"Player")
lotsOfWins.whereKey("wins", greaterThan:150)

var fewWins = PFQuery(className:"Player")
fewWins.whereKey("wins", lessThan:5)

var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([lotsOfWins, fewWins])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // results contains players with lots of wins or only a few wins.
  }
}
```

my issue here is that my tags are in an array, and I don't know how much there is (could be 1, could be 3). So I though about doing a for loop to create a query for every one of them.

my problem is that I can't access the variable outside of this for loop, and I can't declare them before hand as I don't know how much there will be.

something that would look like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tags.count; i++){
   let i = PFQuery(className: "items")
   i.whereKey("tags", equalTo: tags[i])
}

var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([variable1, variable2 ... ])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // results 
  }
}
```

is there a way to achieve such thing?

Comment: Why not use `query.containedIn` or `query.containsAll`?

Comment: Also see https://www.parse.com/questions/query-where-relation-contains-any-object-from-array

Comment: because I want to retrieve objects base on multiple (OR) conditions. Using containsAll would retrieve only objects that contains all my query conditions.

Comment: Right, but `containedIn` will achieve just that. It will be the OR of the tag conditions result with **any** of the tags being matched.

Comment: the documentation says that containedIn is not equalTo. Using containedIn seems to return errors

Comment: I have no idea what that means, could you clarify? `containedIn` is a completely separate constraint from `notEqualTo`. `containedIn` works by matching the key (tag in this case)  against *any* of the items in the array of tags.